# Windows native callback only returns 32 bit result on 64 bit platform

Tags: go

I'm calling a DLL function, that takes a callback function, where the callback function returns a pointer to some data structure, and the DLL will perform some action on the data structure.

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
    "unsafe"
)

type A struct {}
var a = &A{}

func Callback() uintptr {
    ptr := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(a))
    fmt.Printf("Address: 0x%X\n", ptr)
    return ptr
}

func main() {
    dll := windows.MustLoadDLL("some.dll")
    init := dll.MustFindProc("init")
    init.Call(windows.NewCallback(Callback))
    fmt.Printf("This never get prints\n")
}
```

I'm running go on Windows 64-bit machine, the DLL is also 64-bit.

```
$ go version
go version go1.11.4 windows/amd64
```

The above code will print the address of the pointer, which is `0xC000080018`, but the call to the DLL will fail silently. I don't have the source code to the DLL so I can't make it print the value it gets. So I used IDA pro to dynamically debug the program, and I found that the Go callback function is actually returning 32-bit value instead of 64-bit value. This is the final code of the Go callback routine before it returns back to the DLL:

```
main.exe:00000000004537E7     mov     eax, [rcx+rdx-8]
main.exe:00000000004537EB     pop     qword ptr [rcx+rdx-8]
main.exe:00000000004537EF     retn
```

As you can see Go is writing the return value in `eax` instead of `rax`, which will discard the higher address, therefore the DLL will only get `0x80018` and caused errors.

Although I know what's wrong with it, I can't figure out how to fix it.

**Update:**

I've done some digging into Go's implementation of the callback, and found the assembly code at [`src/runtime/sys_windows_amd64.s`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/sys_windows_amd64.s#L354). I noticed that in `runtime·callbackasm1`, the return value is set using `MOVL` instead of `MOVQ`. So I changed it to `MOVQ` and everything worked.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or actually intended, so I will [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29331).

Comment: Fixed in release 1.14.2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was with a bug in Go, which has now been fixed (the comment says in Go 1.14.2, but it might have been before then).

Answer (score 1):

This bug was posted as an issue on golang repo ([issue 29331](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29331)) and fixed by the golang team.